# Setting up the (right) views in order to show an image, the details of it beneath it and enable zooming for the image

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview

What I am trying to do is to present an image at the top of the view and beneath it to show the details of it. 
By now I am using a UITableView and a UIImageView. The UIImageView is at the top of the View and the UITableView beneath the UIImageView. In the UIImageView I load an image and I want to let the user to pan/zoom it. In the UITableView I show in sections the details of the image. Everything works ok, but when I enable zooming in the UIImageView the image covers parts of the tableView. Moreover, I cannot scroll anymore.

What is the correct combiantion of views for achieving the above requirements?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the UIImageView I'd use a UIScrollView with the UIImageView embedded in it, this will allow you to setup pan/zoom within whatever view size you want.